# Haskell - How to avoid typing the same context over and over again?

Tags: haskell

I recently started a little [hobby project](http://github.com/fuzxxl/Unter), where I try to implement the trick-taking card-game Skat (for 3 players). To make it possible to have different kinds of players (like AI, network and local) playing together, I designed an [interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769726/design-of-interface-abstraction) using a typeclass `Player`:

```
class Monad m => Player p m | p -> m where
  playerMessage :: Message answer -> p -> m (Either Error answer,p)
```

I use a `StateT` to wrap up those three players:

```
type PST a b c m x = StateT (Players a b c) m x
```

But now, I have to write a big pile of context in each type signature:

```
dealCards :: (Player a m, Player b m, Player c m, RandomGen g)
  => g -> PST a b c m (SomeOtherState,g)
```

How can I avoid writing this big context again and again?

Comment: Do you have your code online anywhere? You might get more useful advice with more context. The code here feels to me like something that's strictly more general than what you actually need, and could be simplified accordingly by specializing to only what makes sense, but I can't be sure of that without the larger context.

Comment: @camccann It's published on [GitHub](https://github.com/fuzxxl/Unter). The code on github is a bit different because I am currently doing a lot of refactoring to make my life easier.

Comment: @FUXxxl - random comment - you should specify extensions on a per-module basis

Comment: Wow... One day, 233 views, 17 upvotes and 4 stars!

Comment: +1 for combining Skat and Haskell!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- The only thing you can observe from the player class is a function of type

  ```
  playerMessage' :: Message answer -> m (Either Error answer, p)
  ```

  Hence, you can eliminate the class entirely and use an ordinary data type

  ```
  data Player m = Player { playerMessage'
                :: Message answer -> m (Either Error answer, Player m) }
  ```

  This is basically [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769726/design-of-interface-abstraction/5770675#5770675).
- An alternative solution is to move the context into the data type by using GADTs.

  ```
  data PST a b c m x where
      PST :: (Player a m, Player b m, Player c m)
          => StateT (Players a b c) m x -> PST a b c m x
  ```

  In other words, the constraints become part of the data type.
- The best solution is, in my opinion, to scrap the whole thing and redesign it along the lines of the [TicTacToe example](http://projects.haskell.org/operational/examples/TicTacToe.hs.html) from my [operational package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/operational). This design allows you to write each player (human, AI, replay,...) in a specialized monad and later inject everything into a common interpreter.

Comment: I like this approach. So, the way to handle state for the players is to use a more general function like `playerMessageAI :: AiState -> Message answer -> m (Either Error answer, Player)` and use partial application? Okay, I think I got it. PS: You are missing an `m` after `data Player`, but I don't know, whether this is intentional. (Maybe a `newtype` works as well?)

Comment: @yairchu I upvoted both of your answers, as Heinrich Apfelmus gives some extra explanation.

Comment: @FUZxxl: thanks. but I feel like my answer has become redundant. So, I'll just delete it and go sit alone in the dark :/

Comment: @yairchu I feel sorry for you. This happens to me quite often too.

Comment: @yairchu Let's sit there together! However, I will leave mine as it may generate some additional rep. :D

Comment: Strictly speaking, your second bullet is not a GADT but an ordinary data type declared using a [GADT-style declaration](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.4/html/users_guide/data-type-extensions.html#gadt-style).  I am not sure why it is not counted as a GADT, though, because it behaves differently from any data type declared using the Haskell98 syntax.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi The interesting thing is, that the context is actually useful in such a declaration, as opposed to contexts of ordinary datatypes.

Comment: @yairchu: You don't need to do that... :[ You could have at least waited for another upvote in hopes of getting a "Disciplined" badge out of it.

Comment: @FUZxxl: What I said is that even though this data type is declared using a GADT-style declaration, it is still what is called “ordinary data type” in the GHC manual, not a GADT.  Check the GHC manual for definitions.

Comment: @FUZxxl: Err, forgot the `m`, indeed. Fixed. @yairchu: But, but ... I have so few shiny reputation points myself... :'(

Comment: One last question to this approach: If I reify `Player` as a datatype, I still have to carry the monad context, like `Monad m => Player m`, right?

Comment: @FUZxxl: Using GADT-style syntax, you can also put the context on the data constructor, in which case it becomes available automatically by pattern matching. Otherwise, yes, you need to add the `Monad` constraint whenever it's used.

Comment: @camccann I think making it explicit is better, since some players may need `MonadIO` why others don't. (Easier for debugging and testing AIs)

Answer (score 6):

**Update:**
When I tried implementing `dealCards` I have realised that my solution decreases the type-safety by making the players interchangeable. This way you can easily use one player instead of the other which may be undesirable.

---

If you don't mind using `ExistentialQuantification`, I think it can (and should?) be used here. After all, the `dealCards` function should not care or know about `a`, `b` and `c`, right?

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}

import Control.Monad.State
import System.Random

type Message answer = answer
type Error = String

class Monad m => Player p m | p -> m where
  playerMessage :: Message answer -> p -> m (Either Error answer,p)

data SomePlayer m = forall p. Player p m => SomePlayer p

data Players m = Players (SomePlayer m) (SomePlayer m) (SomePlayer m)

type PST m x = StateT (Players m) m x

dealCards :: (RandomGen g, Monad m) => g -> PST m x
dealCards = undefined
```

I think it should be possible to eliminate the `Monad` constraint in a similar way.

Actually, in cases like this I feel like type classes are being overused. Maybe that's a Haskell novice speaking in me, but I'd write this instead:

```
data Player m = Player { playerMessage :: Message answer -> m (Either Error answer, Player m) }
```

Comment: Agreed. In my and [Luke Palmer's opinion](http://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/), existential quantification is always a sign that an ordinary data type will do.

Comment: I'm also inclined to say that if a type class can be represented straightforwardly by record of instance members, that representation is almost always better than messing around with annoying existentials. I usually cite luqui's blog here, but... it looks like @Heinrich already took care of that, heh.

Comment: Note that any argument type eliminated from a function's type by partial application becomes, in a conceptual sense, existential; it exists, even though you can't do anything with it. Using existential types directly is mostly about reifying that concept, which is rarely necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly the better answer is to have a design that doesn't need all those type parameters in the first place.  However, if you really can't get rid of them, and to answer the question as posed, here's a trick I've played:

```
class (Storable.Storable (X, y), Y y) => Signal y
```

Now writing '(Signal y) => ...' will imply all the other typeclasses, and prevent implementation details like Storable from getting into every API.  However, you have to declare instances for Signal.  It's easy because it has no methods, but is probably mostly suitable for when you have few instances but many functions.